# Running a colocated code block for each item in an Ignite cache

Tags: scala, ignite

I have a block of code I want to run for every value in an Ignite cache. The block can be implemented as a function that takes a value from the cache, and returns a void (unit) result. I want the computation to be collocated with the data, such that no values are transmitted over the network at query time.

I have found the [`IgniteCache::query`](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#section-query) function, but it is not exactly what I want. The problem is `query` takes a `ScanQuery` that encapsulates a `IgniteBiPredicate` which is a function that returns a boolean. I'm not interested in evaluating a predicate or returning a value. My function is evaluated exclusively for its side effect (in my case, making an API request to another system).

More simply, `IgniteCache::query` is like a [`filter`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable@filter(p:A=>Boolean):Repr), but I want a [`foreach`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable@foreach(f:A=>Unit):Unit).

Answer (score 1):

You can broadcast a closure [1] and use `IgniteCache.localEntries()` method to iterate through the local data on each node.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-closures#broadcast-methods

Comment: Thanks. I am using partitioned cache mode, with `CacheConfiguration#backups > 0`. How do I make sure every item in the cache is processed exactly once? Or is this already guaranteed somehow?

Comment: `IgniteCache.localEntries(CachePeekMode.PRIMARY)` will return only primary entries.